# What's the use of "(void)0" in __typeof__?

Tags: c

I am currently looking at the `stdatomic.h` header file in ubuntu linux.
What is the use of `(void)0` and comma in `__typeof__ ((void)0, *__atomic_store_ptr)` ?
Doesn't this need nothing?

```
#define atomic_store_explicit(PTR, VAL, MO)             \
  __extension__                             \
  ({                                    \
    __auto_type __atomic_store_ptr = (PTR);             \
    __typeof__ ((void)0, *__atomic_store_ptr) __atomic_store_tmp = (VAL);   \
    __atomic_store (__atomic_store_ptr, &__atomic_store_tmp, (MO)); \
  })
```

Comment: The `(void)` is there to suppress a compiler warning but I'm not sure why they are even using the comma operator here.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92935

Comment: Note well that that macro is deeply implementation-specific (all the dunders provide a good clue).  The answer to the question posed may tell you something interesting about the specific C implementation to which it is targeted (gcc / glibc, I guess), but it won't tell you much about the C language generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will help when `PTR` happens to be a pointer to an array or a function or a pointer to a qualified type. The comma operator in `((void)0,x)` will force L-value conversion. It basically means transforming an object into a value. In a case of arrays it transforms an array in to pointer to its first element. Functions that are transformed to function pointers. The qualified types looses qualifiers like `volatile`, `const` or `_Atomic`.

The l-value conversion happens in pretty much every case except address operator `&`, `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and gcc's `__typeof__` (`typeof` in upcoming C23).

As it was said in the comments the cast to `void` is used to silence warning about unused value of `0`.

1. Pointer to an array

See:

```
int arr[3];
int (*ptr)[3];

atomic_store_explicit(ptr, &arr, XXX);
```

If no L-value conversion was forced then the macro would expand to:

```
__auto_type __atomic_store_ptr = (ptr);
```

which is

```
int (*__atomic_store_ptr)(ptr);
```

and

```
__typeof__ (*__atomic_store_ptr) __atomic_store_tmp = (VAL);
```

which becomes:

```
int __atomic_store_tmp[3] = arr;
```

because dereferencing `int(*)[3]` produces `int[3]`.

It will cause compilation failure due to initialization of an array with a pointer.

With the trick the code above will become:

```
int *__atomic_store_tmp = arr;
```

because `int[3]` is transformed to `int*` by doing l-value conversion.

2. Function pointer.

For function pointers the situation is analogous to a pointer to an array.

```
void foo(void);
void (*ptr)(void);

atomic_store_explicit(ptr, foo, X);
```

Expands to:

```
...
__auto_type __atomic_store_ptr = (PTR);

==>

void (*__atomic_store_ptr)(void) = ptr;
```

and

```
__typeof__ (*__atomic_store_ptr) __atomic_store_tmp = (VAL);

==>

void __atomic_store_tmp(void) = foo;
```

because dereferencing `(void(*)(void)` produces a **function type** `void(void)`. The compilation fails due to initialization of a function with is not allowed in C.

With the trick the above declaration becomes:

```
void (*__atomic_store_tmp)(void) = foo;
```

which compiles fine.

3. A pointer to a qualified type.

Assume:

```
volatile int *ptr;
atomic_store_explicit(ptr, 42, XXX);
```

Now:

```
__auto_type __atomic_store_ptr = (ptr);

==>

volatile int *__atomic_store_ptr = ptr;
```

and:

```
__typeof__ (*__atomic_store_ptr) __atomic_store_tmp = (val);

==>

volatile int __atomic_store_tmp = val;
```

Now the value becomes `volatile` causing subtle issues like worse performance. With l-value conversion the type of `__atomic_store_tmp` becomes unqualified `int`.